# Yii relation in relation and join table attributes

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I have the following models: Products, Addons, AddonTypes, ProductAddons.

The schema is the following:

```
Product
id
name

Addons
id
name
type_id

AddonTypes
id
name

ProductAddons
id
product_id
addon_id
price
```

The question: how can I join these tables in relation to get the products simple like that

ProductAddons::model()->with('addons')->findAll() ?

Q1: Now I get the related addon but I cant figure out, how can I get the addon type?
Q2: How can I get an attribute from a join table. Like the price from ProductAddons?

Comment: Post your PHP-models generated by GII please.

Comment: [Products](http://pastebin.com/m6t1yDAV)  
[ProductAddons](http://pastebin.com/1bmkw1uk)  
[Addons](http://pastebin.com/YEEeNFAD)  
[AddonTypes](http://pastebin.com/8PLEY3ia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you. Using "with()" will always return an array. Also on 1:1 relations... its Yii ;).

```
/* @var $productsWithAddOnly ProductAddons */
$productsWithAddOnly = ProductAddons::model()->with('addons')->findAll();

if (!empty($productsWithAddOnly->addons) && is_array($productsWithAddOnly->addons)) {

    /* @var $addOn Addons */
    foreach ($productsWithAddOnly->addons as $addOn) {
       if (isset($addOn->type)) {
          var_dump($addOn->type);
       } 
    }
}
```

Btw. you should keep Model names singulary ...

**Get all related models from products by:**

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with=array(
    'addons.addons',
);

$prdocutsWithAddOns = Product::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: I want to get a Product with relation from table Addons with relation from AddonsType. So with a "double" relation.

Comment: Ok, check the second example and also check this Link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Comment: I think you didn't understand me, but in the end I got the answer in the Yii documentation.  

So thanks for the help.